# Why doesn't QTreeView.scrollTo() work initially

Tags: python, windows, scroll, pyqt5, qtreeview

The code below just displays a tree view of computer drives. Each time a new file/folder is selected, the view scrolls to make this new selection visible.

Question **1**: While this works, the initial selection after the application is launched doesn't trigger the scroll. Why?

Question **2**: If the instructions:

```
self.my_view.scrollTo(index, QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible)
self.my_view.resizeColumnToContents(0)
```

are inverted:

```
self.my_view.resizeColumnToContents(0)
self.my_view.scrollTo(index, QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible)
```

the first column size is not adjusted either on the initial display, only after. Why?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex, QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTreeView, QMainWindow, QFileSystemModel, QAbstractItemView


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Instance variables
        self.my_view = QTreeView()
        self.my_model = QFileSystemModel()

        # Init FS model to show all computer drives
        model_root_path = str(self.my_model.myComputer())
        self.my_model.setRootPath(model_root_path)

        # Init tree view
        self.my_view.setModel(self.my_model)
        self.my_view.setRootIndex(self.my_model.index(model_root_path))
        self.my_view.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.my_view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

        # Connect selection change events to custom slot
        select_model = self.my_view.selectionModel()
        select_model.currentRowChanged.connect(self.current_row_changed)

        # Main window
        self.setCentralWidget(self.my_view)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 800, 600)

        # Select initial row on view
        focus_path = QDir.currentPath()
        focus_index = self.my_model.index(focus_path)
        self.my_view.setCurrentIndex(focus_index)

    def current_row_changed(self):
        """Current row of the model has changed"""

        # Scroll view to new row
        index = self.my_view.selectionModel().currentIndex()
        self.my_view.scrollTo(index, QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible)
        self.my_view.resizeColumnToContents(0)

        # Show path of current row in window title
        absolute_path = self.my_model.filePath(index)
        self.setWindowTitle(absolute_path)


def main():
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`

---

**Edit**: After using the good solution provided by @ekhumoro, my sample code above worked. However this other piece of code still didn't:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QTimer, QDir, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTreeView, QAbstractItemView, QFileSystemModel, \
    QApplication


class AppWindow(QMainWindow):

    default_folder_path = "."

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.folder_view = FolderTreeView()
        self.folder_view.folder_has_changed.connect(self.folder_changed)
        self.build_ui()
        self.show()

        # Select initial folder
        self.select_initial_folder()

    def build_ui(self):
        main_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QGridLayout(main_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.folder_view)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 800, 600)

    def select_initial_folder(self):
        folder_index = self.folder_view.get_index(AppWindow.default_folder_path)
        if folder_index.isValid():
            self.folder_view.select_folder(folder_index)

    def folder_changed(self, folder_path):
        if not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
            print("Non existing folder:", folder_path)
            return


class FolderTreeView(QTreeView):
    folder_has_changed = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.folder_tree_model = FolderTreeModel()
        self.setModel(self.folder_tree_model)
        self.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

    def select_folder(self, folder_index):
        self.setCurrentIndex(folder_index)

    def currentChanged(self, current, previous):
        super(FolderTreeView, self).currentChanged(current, previous)

        # Scroll the view to current item and resize folder name column
        QTimer.singleShot(50, lambda: self.delayed_scroll(current))

        # Emit signal for other uses
        self.folder_has_changed.emit(self.folder_tree_model.filePath(current))

    def delayed_scroll(self, index):
        self.scrollTo(index, QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible)
        self.resizeColumnToContents(0)

    def get_index(self, folder_path):
        return self.folder_tree_model.index(folder_path)


class FolderTreeModel(QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFilter(QDir.AllDirs | QDir.NoDotAndDotDot)
        self.setRootPath("")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AppWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem may be caused if, by default, the model initialises its current index to the current directory. This would mean that if you set it *again* to the same index, the row-change signal will not be emitted (because nothing changed). This can be fixed by calling the row-change handler directly:

```
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        focus_path = QDir.currentPath()
        focus_index = self.my_model.index(focus_path)
        self.my_view.setCurrentIndex(focus_index)
        self.current_row_changed()

    def current_row_changed(self):
        index = self.my_view.currentIndex()
        self.my_view.scrollTo(index, QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible)
        self.my_view.resizeColumnToContents(0)
        ...
```

As to the second problem: when you call `scrollTo`, it may have to expand several directories in order to select the required index. This could obviously change the width of the first column, so you should always call `resizeColumnToContents` *afterwards* in order to get the correct width.

**UPDATE**:

I think there is also another problem caused by timing issues. The `QFileSystemModel` must work asynchronously to some extent, because it has to request resources from the operating system and then wait for the response. Also, before it gets the response, it cannot know in advance exactly how much data it is going to receive, because the file-system may have been updated while it was waiting. Potentially, the response could include data from a huge directory containing thousands of files. So in order to keep the GUI responsive, the data is processed in batches which are of a sufficient size to fill the current view. If the current index is set *before the window has been shown and all its widgets fully laid out*, there is no guarantee that the view will be able to resize its columns correctly.

This can be fixed by explicitly re-calling the row-change handler via a one-shot timer with a small delay. This should allow the view to recalculate its column widths correctly:

```
    ...    
    focus_path = QDir.currentPath()
    focus_index = self.my_model.index(focus_path)
    self.my_view.setCurrentIndex(focus_index)
    QTimer.singleShot(50, self.current_row_changed)

def current_row_changed(self):
    index = self.my_view.currentIndex()
    self.my_view.scrollTo(index, QAbstractItemView.EnsureVisible)
    self.my_view.resizeColumnToContents(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the signal parameters I had forgotten and for the clear explanation. For Q2, your solution works fine. +1. **But for Q1**: I know the signal slot is already called as the window title is changed, and the problem is the same  if I set the initial index to an existing random path, e.g. `focus_path = "c:/windows/diagnostics/system/Power"`. Calling explicitly the slot doesn't trigger scrolling either.

Comment: @mins See my updated answer. (I had this in my origimal answer, but I thought I had misread your question, so I changed it).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the timer is an improvement, the width is recomputed taking all rows into account (while without it, the width is adjusted using the current row width only). There is no improvement however as regards to the scroll problem. I was wondering if `QFileSystemModel::directoryLoaded` signal couldn't be used in some way in place of the timer, even if it is not linked to the view timing.

Comment: @mins It seems that it ***is*** necessary to request the current index inside the slot, otherwise the index passed via the timer becomes invalid. However, after fixing that problem (see my updated answer), I found I also had to add a small delay in the timer to get the scrolling to work properly.

Comment: Yes it does, with 0 ms it doesn't, with 50 ms it scrolls. Thanks for your time looking at this oddity and devising a good answer :-) Note that in my actual context, the scroll doesn't work, even with 1s delay. Trying to understand.

Comment: @mins What is the specific context? You should also state which platform(s) you are testing on. One of the problems here is that the geometry of the viewport is required in order to calculate the scroll position, and that cannot be done reliably before the window and all its widgets are fully rendered on screen. There is no cross-platform way to determine exactly when that has happened - which is why a timer is needed.

Comment: I'm using W7. My case is: A current item is set in the main window 'constructor'. In the `QTreeView.currentChanged` handler I post a call to a function using the timer. In the latter function I call `scrollTo(current_item)`. I can use whatever delay (e.g. 2 seconds), but while the tree is expanded by `scrollTo`, the current item is not scrolled into the viewport.

Comment: @mins I cannot reproduce that from your description. It all works fine for me (but I'm only able to test on linux).

Comment: I've posted a second example where the scroll doesn't work, if you have time to look at it.

Comment: @mins I already fixed this issue in my second comment above. Do not send a model-index via a timer, because it will become invalidated. Retrieve the current index inside the `delayed_scroll` method.

Comment: Oops, I don't know what I was thinking to :-) Thanks.